# mvc phone number regex "or"

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to make validation for phone number or cellphone number with country prefix (or without) 
for ex:
1. 55-123-1234(home num) or 055-123-1234(cell phone) => [2,3][3][4]
2. or +999-55-123-1234 => +[3][2][3][4]

For now Im using the following regex: `[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{2,3})[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?([0-9]{4,6})$"` but it covers only 1.

the last [3][4] will always be so my question is if there is a way to write => ([2,3]) or (+[3] [2])

The validation needs to cover (+[3] [2]) [3] [4] or ([2,3]) [3] [4] make it valid

If there is any way to do add "or" between (+[3][2]) to ([2,3])?
or maybe there is other way to it to make it valid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OR* in regex is done with the `|` character.
`+[3][2]` or `[2,3]` is then written : `\+\d{3}\-\d{2}|\d{2,3}`
So for your complete regex, you can try the following :
`(?:\+\d{3}[-. ]?\d{2}|\d{2,3})[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/AxOejJ/1)

Comment: Thanks, I know that "|" is "or" operator but from your reply i see that executing "or" query I needs to set it as (?:a|b)
am I right?

Comment: @boasis: Yes, `(?:)` is a non capturing group (like a set of parenthesis in a standard expression). If you don't use it, your second part of the regex (`[3][4]`) would be part of the right member of the OR.